# Error after ionic build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

System - Ubuntu

I have done the following:

```
.bashrc

export ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk

export PATH=$PATH:/root/Android/Sdk/tools
```

After I try the do the above I try to run `sudo ionic build android` in my console.

**Console output:**

```
sudo ionic build android

Running command: /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.615 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Answer (score 1):

first,you should not run cordova CLI commands with sudo, this causes errors because the user used to run sudo commands is not the same your user, so if you configure path for your user, it's not changed for the sudo user.

you just need sudo to run `npm install -g ...` command, but not for cordova or ionic commands.

That said, it does not seem to be the cause of your issue.

> Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>   peer not authenticated

This message seems to indicate you have a SSL issue when trying to download dependencies. Are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: Without sudo after `ionic platform add android` i get `Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/aiduryagin/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.1.0/package/.npmignore'` And i don't use proxy.

Comment: you have this error because you created the project with sudo, so now your regular user does not have permissions to write in it. You wan either try to change owner of the project files or try with a new project created without sudo.

Comment: about your "real" issue, can you run java -version to check the version number of java?

Comment: After `sudo ionic platform add android` all is ok. But after `ionic build` `cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test1/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test1/platforms/android/android.json'`

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: do not use sudo with cordova or ionic commands. That means `ionic create yourproject`not `sudo ionic create yourproject` and then `ionic platform add android` and `ionic build android` not `sudo ionic ...` But again the issue you have is not about path so it's not related with sudo or not, but more on SSL certificate in your jvm.

Comment: Tried create an app without sudo. Catch `Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/aiduryagin/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.1.0/package/.npmignore'
` after `ionic platform add android`

Comment: previous use of sudo with the cordova cli must have copied many files with root rights in the .cordova folder. You can either change the rights of those files or remove the .cordova folder of your user (or rename it in case you're not sure)